# Does Removing a User From PS4 Delete the Account?

Tags: ps4

I had recently purchased a refurbished PS4 but have had various issues with it. I decided to buy a brand new one but I want to remove my user from the refurbished one before I return it. Since I have created the account, I have downloaded dlc, updated games, and done various other things. I have already signed in and redownloaded the games on the new PS4. My question is, will any of that be lost when I remove my user from the refurbished PS4, or will it not affect my account at all? I know it may be a small question to post, but when I go to delete it I get the warning that I have to initialize the PS4 to remove the user, and that worries me. I have not found anything online explaining this either. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your games and dlc etc are tied to your account, not your console.

You can return the refurbished console and download all your content to your new console.